# Does Typescript use the type annotation for a variable or the specific type of the definition?

Tags: typescript

The following code suggests to me that even though I specify a union type for a variable instead of one of the types making up the union, that `tsc` uses the specific type for a variable.

This code fails to compile with TypeScript 3.9.2:

```
src/test.ts:49:25 - error TS2339: Property 'language' does not exist on type 'never'.
  The intersection 'CommandNotSelected & SayHelloCommand' was reduced to 'never' because property 'commandType' has conflicting types in some constituents.

35     console.log(command.language);
```

```
enum CommandType {
    SAY_HELLO,
    COMMAND_NOT_SELECTED,
}

interface SayHelloCommand {
    commandType: CommandType.SAY_HELLO;
    language: string;
}

interface CommandNotSelected {
    commandType: CommandType.COMMAND_NOT_SELECTED;
}

type Command = SayHelloCommand | CommandNotSelected;

function isSayHelloCommand(c: Command): c is SayHelloCommand {
    return c.commandType === CommandType.SAY_HELLO;
}

let command: Command = {
    commandType: CommandType.COMMAND_NOT_SELECTED,
};

function f() {
    command = {
        commandType: CommandType.SAY_HELLO,
        language: 'foobar',
    };
}

f();

if (isSayHelloCommand(command)) {
    console.log(command.language);
}
```

I can get this to compile by swapping out the code to

```
function initialCommand(): Command {
    return {
        commandType: CommandType.COMMAND_NOT_SELECTED,
    };
}
let command = initialCommand();
```

or

```
let command: Command = {
    commandType: CommandType.COMMAND_NOT_SELECTED,
} as Command;
```

I assumed that TypeScript would use `Command` for the type instead of `CommandNotSelected` and modify its type as it sees modifications to the `command`.

Comment: @Shlang I wasn't asking about changing the type in f(). In any case, the type doesn't change in the assignment in f(), as it's setting it to the other type in the Command union. I was more curious why command isn't really a Command even with the ': Command' type annotation.